# How do I return a typescript enum value based on enum key (from string) for multiple enum types?

Tags: typescript

I have an environment variable coming into my app as a string and have built a config method to validate and return an enum value based on enum key (from string):

```
import { LedMatrix, RowAddressType, MuxType } from 'rpi-led-matrix'

// Validate and return valid MatrixOptions.rowAddressType
export const configRowAddressType = (
  configRowAddressType?: string,
): RowAddressType => {
  if (!configRowAddressType) {
    return LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().rowAddressType
  }

  const rowAddressType = configRowAddressType as keyof typeof RowAddressType

  const keys = Object.keys(RowAddressType)
  if (keys.includes(rowAddressType)) {
    return RowAddressType[rowAddressType]
  }

  if (rowAddressType) {
    console.error(
      `supplied rowAddressType key of ${rowAddressType} is not a valid option, assigning default of ${
        LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().rowAddressType
      }.`,
    )
  }

  return LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().rowAddressType
}
```

It works. However, I have another method that looks very similar that validates and types another variable representing another enum key:

```
// Validate and return valid MatrixOptions.multiplexing
export const configMultiplexing = (configMultiplexing?: string): MuxType => {
  if (!configMultiplexing) {
    return LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().multiplexing
  }

  const multiplexing = configMultiplexing as keyof typeof MuxType

  const keys = Object.keys(MuxType)
  if (keys.includes(multiplexing)) {
    return MuxType[multiplexing]
  }

  if (multiplexing) {
    console.error(
      `supplied multiplexing key of ${multiplexing} is not a valid option, assigning default of ${
        LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().multiplexing
      }.`,
    )
  }

  return LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().multiplexing
}
```

I'll have a total of five or so of these similar methods. It seems redundant, yet I'm struggling with how to return a dynamic enum type. Here's a rough example that *could* work, perhaps not ideal:

```
export const configEnumValueByKey = (inputValue: string, enumType: RowAddressType | MuxType | SomethingElse | AnotherSomething | MoreSomething | YetAnother): RowAddressType | MuxType | SomethingElse | AnotherSomething | MoreSomething | YetAnother => {
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way I can refactor for a single method that handles dynamically set return types?

Comment: What is the return type of `LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions()`?

Comment: `LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions()` type is `MatrixOptions`.

Comment: And what is the type of `RowAddressType` / `MuxType`? Is it a `Record` or something else?

Comment: Those are enums:

`export declare enum RowAddressType {
    /**
     * Corresponds to direct setting of the row.
     */
    Direct = 0,
    /**
     * Used for panels that only have A/B. (typically some 64x64 panels)
     */
    AB = 1,
    /**
     * Direct row select
     */
    DirectRow = 2,
    /**
     * ABC addressed panels
     */
    ABC = 3,
    /**
     * 4 = ABC Shift + DE direct
     */
    ABCShift = 4
}`

Comment: `export declare enum MuxType {
    Direct = 0,
    Stripe = 1,
    Checker = 2,
    Spiral = 3,
    ZStripe = 4,
    ZnMirrorZStripe = 5,
    Coreman = 6,
    Kaler2Scan = 7, }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on something similar, so I expanded it for you. I'm not sure what to say, so here are some resources if you're interested.
[Function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) [Type generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

**Edit**: fix to return defaultValue if the rawValue is one of the enum values

```
//Enums
enum Locations {
    Address1 = 0,
    Address2 = 1,
    Address3 = 'SDF'
}
enum Actions {
    Scan = 0,
    Print = 1,
    SelfDestruct = 2
}

//Wrappers around the actual validate function, which can be left untouched
const configLocations = (location?: string) => {
    return validateEnum(Locations, location, Locations.Address1);
}
const configActionType = (actionType?: string) => {
    //No default value
    return validateEnum(Actions, actionType);
}

const val = configLocations('SDF'); //Will be the default value, accurate type
const val2 = configActionType('Print')
console.log(val, val2);

//Generic type for the enum list
type Enum<E> = Record<keyof E, number | string> & { [k: number]: string };
// Use overloads to correctly type return value, if `defaultValue` is present.
// Quirk: `rawValue` cannot be an optional parameter because we want to type `defaultValue` as required. Must specify undefined explicitly in some cases

function validateEnum<E extends Enum<E>>(enumList: E, rawValue: string | undefined): E[keyof E] | undefined;
function validateEnum<E extends Enum<E>>(enumList: E, rawValue: string | undefined, defaultValue: E[keyof E]): E[keyof E];
function validateEnum<E extends Enum<E>>(
    enumList: E,
    rawValue: string | undefined,
    defaultValue?: E[keyof E]
) : E[keyof E] | undefined {
    
    if (rawValue === undefined) {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    // Object.keys on an enum also returns the values (for non-string values). console.log(Object.keys(Locations)) -> ["0", "1", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3"]
    // We can just filter out the keys that are not parsable as numbers (numeric enum keys are not allowed anyways).
    const enumKeys = Object.keys(enumList).filter(k => isNaN(Number(k)) === true);
    if (enumKeys.includes(rawValue)) {
        return enumList[rawValue as keyof E];
    }

    console.error(
        `supplied rowAddressType key of ${rawValue} is not a valid option` +
        (defaultValue ? `. Replacing with a default value of: ${defaultValue}.` : '')
    );
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: I feel this meets the requirement of the bounty and I'm learning a lot from it. Thank you. The only change I made was, `if (!rawValue) {
    return defaultValue
  }` as environment vars may be coming in as empty strings (falsy value).

Comment: @ChristopherStevens I figure I should let you know if you try `console.log(configLocations('0') === Locations.Address1)`, you will get false. If the rawValue is '0', '1' or '2' or any of the enum 'values', even though it's invalid, it won't get replaced by the default value. This can be very misleading, because you'll have a valid enum type in Typescript that won't be equal to any enum members.

Comment: It's because of the way enums are mapped in JS. This doesn't happen for string enums members. So, we can use `Object.keys` and filter out the values that are parsable as numbers. I've updated the code snippet.